# Microsoft Teams Graph API: Add channel to teams is failing with a 404

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, microsoft-teams

I trying to add channels to a newly created Microsoft Teams using Microsoft Graph API and using an Invoke-RestMethod with the following Powershell running in Azure Functions

I tried both v1.0 and beta and searched high and low for examples on this:

```
# code that successfully creates a team based on existing Office 365 Group not shown, but is
# comes from [https://github.com/martinagrom/Ignite2018GroupsGovernanceToolkit][1], f1-CreateGroup and f2-CreateTeam

function AddContent ($folderName) {
Write-Output "Inside of AddContent"
$Body = @{
    "displayName"= "$folderName"
    "description"= "Add decription"
}
$bodyJSON = $body | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Output "Adding channel $($folderName)"
Write-Output "bodyJSON $($bodyJSON)"
try {
    Write-Output "creating channel on https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/$($TeamID)/channels"
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod `
                            -Method POST `
                            -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/$($TeamID)/channels" `
                            -ContentType 'application/json' `
                            -Headers $script:APIHeader `
                            -Body $bodyJSON `
                            -ErrorAction Stop

    $TeamResult = $result.id
    Write-Output "Channel created: ID:[$TeamResult]"
} catch [System.Net.WebException] {
    Write-Output "AddChannelOnExistingTeam: $($TeamResult.error.code) => $($TeamResult.error.message)"
    Write-Output "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/$($TeamID)/channels   ---    $script:APIHeader --- $body"
    If ($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__) {
        $crap = ($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ ).ToString().Trim();
        Write-Output $crap;
    }
    If  ($_.Exception.Message) {
        $crapMessage = ($_.Exception.Message).ToString().Trim();
        Write-Output $crapMessage;
    }
    $result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($result)
    $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
    $reader.DiscardBufferedData()
    $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd();
    Write-Output $responseBody
throw "AddChannelOnExistingTeam: $($TeamResult.error.code) => $($TeamResult.error.message)"
}
catch {
    Write-Output "AddChannelOnExistingTeam: Another Exception caught: [$($_.Exception)]"
    throw "AddChannelOnExistingTeam: $($TeamResult.error.code) => $($TeamResult.error.message)"
}
}

# The team has just been created based on an Office365 group by code (not shown) and the Group/Team ID is in the $TeamResult
# I do a sleep to ensure Team is ready, probably not necessary. Plenty of Write-Out to debug progress. Log futher down
# I grap a list of folder names from a document library and is calling the above function with each name to create a corrosponding channel

Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
$TeamID = $TeamResult
$TeamChannels = $TeamInfo.TeamChannels
Write-Output "TeamChannels $($TeamChannels) on TeamID $($TeamID)"
$sourcesite = $TeamChannels.SubString(0,$TeamChannels.lastIndexOf('/'))
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:SPO_P -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($env:SPO_U, $secpasswd)
connect-PnPOnline -Credentials $mycreds -url $sourcesite 
$folders = Get-pnpFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $TeamChannels.SubString($TeamChannels.lastIndexOf('/')+1)

ForEach ($folder in $folders) {
if ($folder.Name -ne "Forms") {
    AddContent($folder.Name)
}
}
```

[Create Group and Teams code from Martina Grom](https://github.com/martinagrom/Ignite2018GroupsGovernanceToolkit)

And the log output:

```
2018-12-10T12:15:07.373 [Info] TeamChannels https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects/Template on TeamID xxxxxx-e3ab-4e3a-b81d-c540c8e2e6ea
2018-12-10T12:15:08.889 [Info] Inside of AddContent
2018-12-10T12:15:08.889 [Info] Adding channel 01. Gate - Documentation
2018-12-10T12:15:08.889 [Info] bodyJSON {
    "displayName":  "01. Gate - Documentation",
    "description":  "Add decription"
}
2018-12-10T12:15:08.889 [Info] creating channel on https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/xxxxxx-e3ab-4e3a-b81d-c540c8e2e6ea/channels
2018-12-10T12:15:08.920 [Info] AddChannelOnExistingTeam:  =>
2018-12-10T12:15:08.920 [Info] https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/xxxxxx-e3ab-4e3a-b81d-c540c8e2e6ea/channels   ---    System.Collections.Hashtable --- System.Collections.Hashtable
2018-12-10T12:15:08.920 [Info] 404
2018-12-10T12:15:08.920 [Info] The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
2018-12-10T12:15:08.920 [Info] {
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{\"message\":\"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://api.teams.skype.com/beta/teams('xxxxxx-e3ab-4e3a-b81d-c540c8e2e6ea')/channels'.\"}",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "10523b5c-55b7-4a2e-a428-f94b7f0fa88a",
      "date": "2018-12-10T12:15:08"
    }
  }
}

2018-12-10T12:15:08.952 [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.CreateTeam. System.Management.Automation: AddChannelOnExistingTeam:  => . AddChannelOnExistingTeam:  => .
2018-12-10T12:15:08.983 [Error] Function completed (Failure, Id=xxxxxxx-52cd-45c7-9bd8-5e509353ddfc, Duration=64753ms)

# End of Log
```

So the POST `to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/TeamID/channels` get reverted to `https://api.teams.skype.com/beta/teams('TeamID')/channels` and fails with a `404`

If I go to Microsoft Graph Explorer and enters the exact same information the channel(s) gets created.

What am I missing? Is it missing API Permissions? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried delaying the creation of the channel for a few seconds? It may be that the team just hasn't been fully propagated when you're attempting to add the channel to it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Marc, I do actually have a 60 seconds sleep between the creation of the Team and the creation of the first channel

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the error, pure copy-paste blindness… :(

The Invoke-RestMethod I copied was a PUT method and that gives the 404 error when you try using it to create channels.

So when I changed it to a POST method it started working. I edited the source.